# JS/ES6: Do I need to re-export module after setting an attribute on it?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

As far as I understood from the module system, whenever I `import 'some_module'` inside a file, I will always get the same instance of that module, and not a different instance on every import.

But if that's true, I kind of don't understand this pattern I've seen in some apps:

```
// in a 'config_some_module.js' file
import SomeModule from 'some_module';

SomeModule.attribute = 'something';

export default SomeModule;

// in a different file;
import SomeModule from './config_some_module';
```

If every time I import a module I get the same instance (and not a new instance), then why is it needed to re-export that module to access it with the configuration that was done on the previous file?

Also, a second question: if that's NOT needed, how to be sure that in the second file the import will get the module when that property is already set? I assume that if both imports get you the same instance, then eventually the property will be present in `SomeModule` on the second file, but maybe the pattern I mentioned above is usefull because you can be sure that the changes to the module were already applied?

Comment: You really should treat exports as immutable. Instead of default-exporting an immutable object, use named exports, and then do `export * from 'some_module'; export const attribute = 'something';` in your config module that you would import as `import * as SomeModule from './config_some_module';`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you need to `export` is because otherwise, `config_some_module.js` would only be creating a *side-effect*. If you want to `import` from it directly, you need to `export` a value. If you don't `export` anything from `config_some_module.js`, you'd need to `import` the modified object with the side-effect by doing this:

```
// in 'config_some_module.js' file
import SomeModule from 'some_module';

SomeModule.attribute = 'something';
```

```
// in a different file;
import './config_some_module'; // introduce side-effect
import SomeModule from 'some_module'; // access modified object
```

One "gotcha" to keep in mind is that the side-effect will only occur once, no matter how many times the `config_some_module.js` is imported.

Lastly, the order in which you execute the `import` statements in the consumer does not matter as long as your usage occurs after both.

Comment: regarding your very last words - since ES6 imports are static you always need to declare all imports before any other statements

Comment: The imports don't necessarily occur in the same file though, so it's still possible to use the object before the side-effect occurs.

Comment: @amankkg you don't need to declare them at the top of the file, they're "hoisted"

Comment: @amankkg Not always true, for example you can do `import('module').then()`

Comment: @XanderLuciano you're right, but dynamic imports are not ES2015/ES6, an example of the possible issue even with ES6 imports is already given from above